# Configure ffmpeg to use concat

Tags: android, c++, linux, ffmpeg, android-ndk

**This is my jni 'c' Code For Concatinate a list of mp3 files in sdcard using ffmpeg in Android**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Test_Mp3_Merger_Audio_mergeAudio(JNIEnv *env,
        jclass someclass, jstring inputFile, jstring outFile) {
    log_message("Starting to trim video");

    int numberOfArgs = 8;
    char** arguments = calloc(numberOfArgs, sizeof(char*));
    char start[5], duration[5];
    const char *in, *out;


    in = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, inputFile, 0);
    out = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, outFile, 0);
    //ffmpeg -f concat -i mergelist.txt -c copy a.mp3 // this comand worked pecrfect in my computer terminal..
    arguments[0] = "ffmpeg";
    arguments[1] = "-f";
    arguments[2] = "concat";
    arguments[3] = "-i";
    arguments[4] = in;
    arguments[5] = "-c";
    arguments[6] = "copy";
    arguments[7] = out;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfArgs; i++) {
        log_message(arguments[i]);
    }
    log_message("Printed all");

    ffmpeg_main(numberOfArgs, arguments);
    log_message("Finished");
    free(arguments);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, inputFile, in);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, outFile, out);
    return 0;
}
```

The below is my config.h generated with config.mak
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VBZ6KJJazSWHBqQWJpWHhuZnM/view?usp=sharing

**And Whenever i call the native method trim()
i got the error message   Unknown input format: 'concat'.**

**But the concat.c is showing as compiled when compiling with ndk
What is wrong ?**

Answer (score 1):

concat.c is the concat protocol. `-f concat -i ...` invokes the concat demuxer, which is  FFmpeg/libavformat/[concatdec.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/f587ed0cbbda2de85d0fb34a4fdca89ccb1f1e61/libavformat/concatdec.c)